# Rollback if one insert fails, when using ScriptRunner "runScript" method

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, ibatis, ojdbc

```
Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = datasource.getConnection();

        ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(con);
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filePath");
        sr.runScript(reader);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (con!=null) try {con.close();}catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
```

Above is the snippet I'm using to execute the SQL script file.

If I have multiple inserts inside the script, I want to execute all the inserts inside a transaction, where If one fails, nothing should be written into the database.

And I want to handle this from the code, instead of the script.

Comment: You can use `commit()` and `rollback()` (along with `setAutoCommit(false)`) method to control the transaction. If an insert fails and data is still written into the DB, you most probably have auto commit turned on.

Comment: I'd also be helpful if you provided `ScriptRunner.runScript()` method as well.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov It's a predefined method in 'ibatis' library. It's not a method I implemented.

Comment: According to [this](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/jdbc/ScriptRunner.html) docs there's `setStopOnError()` and `setAutoCommit()` methods available. You may try playing with them (if you have not already done that) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved this by setting the 'StopOnError' parameter to true.

```
        ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(con);
        sr.setStopOnError(true);
```